# prob with formData -> Fetch

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, form-data

I know this question is frequent but I can't find the right solution reading all the posts about Fetch and formData :

I have a lot of pseudo-forms written in JS in different divs to load images using a unique common function

```
 function uploadImage(ref,rep,int,num,typ,div){  
    
 let form = '<span class="uploader">';
     form+= '<input id="rep-'+num+'" value="'+rep+'"><br>'; // upload directory
     form+= '<input id="ref-'+num+'" value="'+ref+'"><br>'; // image name to use
     form+= '<input id="typ-'+num+'" value="'+typ+'"><br>'; // type of image
     form+= '<input id="div-'+num+'" value="'+div+'"><br>'; // where to display it once loaded on server
     form+= '<input type="file" class="fileimg" id="file-'+num+'">';
     form+= '<button onclick="saveImage('+num+')">'+int+'</button>'; 
     form+= '</span>';
    
     return form
 }
```

the code calling the function for 1st picture:

```
 document.getElementById('img-1').innerHTML = uploadImage('name-of-the-image','dir-to-put-the-file/','ADD AN IMAGE HERE',1,0,'img-1'));
```

and now the JS to fetch img to server:

```
 function saveImage(n) {

   let rep = document.getElementById('rep-'+n).value, // dir
       ref = document.getElementById('ref-'+n).value, // name
       typ = document.getElementById('typ-'+n).value, // type
       div = document.getElementById('div-'+n).value; // div.id

   const url = "upload-imgs.php?imgname="+ref+"&directory="+rep+"&typeimg="+typ
   const files = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files;
   formData = new FormData();

   for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      let file = files[i];
      console.log('FILE = '+file.name);
      formData.append('image', file);
   }

   fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData
   }).then(response => {
      if( response.status==200 && response.ok == true) {
        return response.text().then( text => displayIf(text) )
      }
   });

 }
```

PHP write the image with the right name at the right place dependind the right type of image (photo, graph, plan, ...)  then return `echo $dir.$new_name` and the function `displayIt(img)` shows the new image in the right div

It works perfectly but only for the first image loaded. I think the prob is coming from formData which is to reset, but despite testing different possibilities I cant't find the right one:

```
    if( response.status==200 && response.ok == true) {
        return response.text().then( text => displayIt(text) )
        formData.delete('image'); // log :  unreachable code after return statement
    }
```

Adding `formData.reset()` instead, or in the `displayIt(img)` function, doesn't solve the prob: same log. Where am I wrong?

Comment: ...sorry its not a prob of several images in the same form as suggested above by the person who have closed my post, but how to send several images one by one using the same common form.

Comment: solved : instead of `const files = document.querySelector('[type=file]').files;` (...the first one founded) I use `const files = getElementById('file-'+n).files;`

Comment: thx for reopening ;-)